# Failed to create session. unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, electron, selenium-chromedriver

I'm executing an automated test with Electron by using Selenium by using the following code:

```js
    const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    var Application = require('spectron').Application;
    var assert = require('assert');
    
    const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        // The "9515" is the port opened by chrome driver.
        .usingServer('http://localhost:9515')
        .withCapabilities({
            'goog:chromeOptions': {
                // Here is the path to your Electron binary.
                binary: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
            },
        })
        .forBrowser('electron') // note: use .forBrowser('electron') for selenium-webdriver <= 3.6.0
        .build();
    
    describe('Application launch', function () {
        var app;
        jest.setTimeout(30000);
        beforeEach(function () {
            app = new Application({
                path: 'node_modules/.bin/electron',
                args: ['--headless', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
            });
            return app.start();
        });
    
        afterEach(function () {
            if (app && app.isRunning()) {
                return app.stop();
            }
        });
    
        it('click a button', function* () {
            yield driver.sleep(5000);
        });
    });
```

But I'm obtaining the following error:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: License should be a valid SPDX license expression
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ jest --NODE_ENV=test
 FAIL  src/__test__/App.spec.jsx (10.623 s)
  Application launch
    × click a button (6564 ms)

  ● Application launch › click a button

    Failed to create session.
    unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed.
      (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
      (The process started from chrome location C:\Users\vipul\appname\src\node_modules\spectron\lib\launcher.bat is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

      at startWebDriverSession (src/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:72:15)
      at Function.newSession (src/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:58:45)
      at Object.remote (src/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:73:22)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.878 s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've tried to add even the args suggested by several answers in other stackoverflow questions like --headless or --no-sandbox but even those not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this file

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox");
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # this
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infos")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
element_text = driver.page_source

print(element_text)
```